# CoderByte says all of my testcases are wrong?

Tags: java, string, reverse

I tried coderbyte and looks something is wrong with it. The first challenge is simply to reverse a string. I did this in java:

```
import java.util.*; 
import java.io.*;

class Main {

  public static String FirstReverse(String str) {
    char[] chars = str.toCharArray();
    String ret = "";
    for (int i = chars.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
      ret += chars[i];
    }
    return ret;
  }

  public static void main (String[] args) {  
    // keep this function call here     
    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print(FirstReverse(s.nextLine())); 
  }

}
```

It said, that three test cases had wrong output and there was the correct output. I tried running the code with the specified cases and it printed the same string as correct output for that case. So I tried resubmitting it and it said that only one test case was correct and all other had wrong out put. So I said OK and rewrote my code this way:

```
import java.util.*; 
import java.io.*;

class Main {

  public static String FirstReverse(String str) {
    return new StringBuilder(str).reverse().toString();
  }

  public static void main (String[] args) {  
    // keep this function call here     
    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print(FirstReverse(s.nextLine())); 
  }

}
```

Unfortunately it still says only one test case was successful... Any ideas what happened? Thanks

Comment: I just ran second example and it finishes with 2 test cases failed (no idea how many there are). I think that service is buggy rght now.

Comment: + I have resubmitted the exact same solution - now 6 cases failed. CodingGame is far better :)

Comment: @Antoniossss thanks I will try the CodingGame... I will try to leave this question open for couple more days if someone finds something out...

Comment: I had this happen with the bracket matching problem. I took the alleged "failed" cases and ran them through and they passed. I actually think something is buggy with Coderbyte and it's concerning if companies are actually going to take the interview test results as gospel.

Comment: I'm facing the same problem now with the factorial function. I posted a correct solution and some test cases failed. I reposted the same solution and previous test cases passes but one that previously passed, now fails.

Comment: As an admin, I can also see 3 hidden answers below that mention similar experiences. And I also personally found that this person's test case failed incorrectly: https://coderbyte.com/results/karina9906:First%20Factorial:TypeScript  I'm surprised companies rely on tools like CoderByte for hiring. It's disappointing.